# Multiple POSIX message queues

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

I want to make a server and multiple client application using POSIX message queues. This is my client side simplified code. I deleted string, memory, and other operations for a simple illustration.

Client:

```
// Set attributes of client queue
attr.mq_flags = 0;
attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;
attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

// Create client queue
mq_client = mq_open(sqname_client, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0644, &attr);
// Open server queue
mq_server = mq_open(sqname_server, O_WRONLY);

// Send message to the server
mq_send(mq_server, message, MSG_SIZE, 0);

// Wait for receiving a message back from server
while (1)
{
    bytes_read = mq_receive(mq_client, message, MSG_SIZE, NULL);
    message[bytes_read] = '\0';
    printf("\nMessage from server to client: %s\n",message);
}
// Clean-up
mq_close(mq_server);
mq_unlink(sqname_client);
mq_close(mq_client);
```

Server:

```
// Set attributes of server queue
attr.mq_flags = 0;
attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;
attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

// Create the server queue
mq_server = mq_open(sqname_server, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0644, &attr);

// Wait for receiving a message from the client
while (1)
{
    ssize_t bytes_read;

    bytes_read = mq_receive(mq_server, message, MSG_SIZE, NULL);
    // Send the respond through the client's message queue
    mq_client = mq_open(sqname_client, O_WRONLY);
    mq_send(mq_client, "I got your message client", MSG_SIZE, 0);
}
// Clean-up
mq_close(mq_server);
mq_close(mq_client);
mq_unlink(sqname_server);
```

This works pretty well for sending messages from client to server. But server's respond to client does not appear on the client side. What can be the reason?

Comment: Was the necessary error checking omitted for brevity?  In particular, are you sure the queues are successfully opened?

Comment: Yes queues are opening successfully. I tried both of them one sided by disabling the other queue. And they work, my problem is running two queues at the same time. Do they work at the same time without any effort?

Comment: I filled in the blanks, compiled and ran this fine.  You didn't have a printf for the server side so perhaps you missed that it worked?  One bug is that you keep opening the client queue in the server's while loop but that's not going to affect a test case of a message or two.